# Getting the output of a function?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm writing a function that replaces certain letters. When it is done, I want the value to be set to a variable, so I can the function's output to the local storage.

Here's some of the code:

```
onclick="functionName();
var resultvar = functionName();
localStorage.setItem('name', resultvar);
alert('done');"
```

Comment: Is there any other code ?

Comment: So just to be clear: as it is, you are not getting "the result" in that variable `resultVar`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the onclick event only accepts functions. Either way it's generally a best practice to call a single function from an event handler, and run all your code inside that function. It's also better to attach the event handler rather than use an html attribute.

I'm going to assume the element is an anchor.

Suggested Code:
HTML:

```
<a id="whatever">Click me</a>
```

JS:

```
var el = document.getElementById("whatever");
el.addEventListener("click", clickHandlerFunctionName, false);

function clickHandlerFunctionName(event) {
  //functionName(); You do not need to call this twice if it both does what you need AND returns the value you want.
  var resultvar = functionName();
  localStorage.setItem('name', resultvar);
  alert('done');
}

function functionName() {
  var resultvar;
  //do stuff
  return resultvar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a return in your function, it would look like the following:

```
function functionName() {
  return "your result";
}

var result = functionName();

localStorage.setItem('name', result);
```

You can read more about the return function here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the functionName() is a function your defining, use the return keyword:

```
return [YOUR_VARIABLE]
```

this can be a int, string, double etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
function replacer( str, regex, replace ) {
  return str.replace( regex, replace )
}

localStorage.setItem( 'hello', replacer( 'Hello World', /\s/, '_' ) )
```

This code will stuff `Hello_World` into local storage under the key `hello`